# AmCharts 4 handling null data

Tags: javascript, amcharts, jsonresponse

I am working on AmCharts where I load data dynamically. Sometimes, there may be null data sent from the response. I need to handle null data in AmCharts4.
 [In this link I see the example for Amcharts3 handling null data](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v3/tutorials/gracefully-handle-charts-data/)

```
var chart = am4core.create("reason_for_failure", am4charts.PieChart);
        // Add and configure Series
        var pieSeries = chart.series.push(new am4charts.PieSeries());
        pieSeries.dataFields.value = "litres";
        pieSeries.dataFields.category = "country";
        pieSeries.slices.template.stroke = am4core.color("#fff");
        pieSeries.slices.template.strokeWidth = 2;
        pieSeries.slices.template.strokeOpacity = 1;

        // This creates initial animation
        pieSeries.hiddenState.properties.opacity = 1;
        pieSeries.hiddenState.properties.endAngle = -90;
        pieSeries.hiddenState.properties.startAngle = -90;

        chart.data = [];
```

Comment: you can use a ternary operator to check whether data is null or it has data like this 
data ? <Chart /> : <Loader />

Comment: if you can post the code , it will be helpful to post the solution

Comment: You can use any demo available in AmCharts4 demo page. Make the chart data set as null (chart.data = [ ]).

Comment: you can post the code that you have tried , https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Posted a sample data.

Comment: Found solution from this link https://codepen.io/team/amcharts/pen/zyvQjd?editors=0010

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the sample code he provided is more/less straight out of one of our Pie Chart demos, e.g. [Pie Chart With Legend](https://www.amcharts.com/demos/pie-chart-with-legend/), so I mixed and matched that with the solution in the [mirror GitHub issue](https://github.com/amcharts/amcharts4/issues/670) (demo link on the bottom).

Again, the [`beforevalidated`](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/reference/xychart/#beforevalidated_event) [event](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/concepts/event-listeners/) is perfect for handling the case of the `chart.data` being assigned an empty array, e.g.

```js
chart.events.on("beforevalidated", function(event) {
  // check if there's data
  console.log(event.target.data.length);
  if (event.target.data.length == 0) {
    // handle null data here
  }
});
```

It would have to be the `beforevalidated` event, because if there's no data, `beforedatavalidated` does not trigger.

Demo:

https://codepen.io/team/amcharts/pen/88d11b5385a2669319c1a0fcdaa1e199/